# Is it a good practice to keep a blank exception block enclosing our code in java?

Tags: exception, crash

I want to know whether it is good to have a  blank exception block for the code.
If we have an blank exception then I think there is no way that our app crashes.Is this true?
I was writing an android application which makes some rest calls. the application crashes so because sometimes there is a change in the json format.

Comment: What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: Yes it's true but it should be last option in code. we should try to catch specific exception which help us during debugging than you can add blank exception.

Comment: you really need to make clear what you are talking about. specify what language and scenario and gve an example

Comment: Exceptions alert you about problems. Hiding them postpones them until they are a lot bigger.

Answer (score 1):

It's never good practice to "swallow" an exception, especially if the reason is to avoid propagating the exception to the top of the stack, causing the VM to terminate.  If there is an exception, then it needs to be caught *and handled* at some point.  At the very least, you need to log something somewhere so you can find the real problem later, and resolve it.

However, it is good practice to prevent any exception from escaping out the top of the stack.  You just shouldn't have an empty catch block doing that.